# Проверка ввода с клавиатуры в JSpinner

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Мне необходимо поставить проверку на ввод с клавиатуры в JSpinner. Проверка следующая - чтобы вводились только числа из заданного диапазона. У JSpinner уже есть такая проверка по умолчанию, но она срабатывает только когда фокус был переведён на другой объект или нажата Enter. Моя реализация представлена ниже:

```
JSpinner jspNumber = new JSpinner(SpinnerNumberModel(3, 1, 64, 1));
jspNumber.setBounds(150, 80, 100, 20);
JFormattedTextField tf =   ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)jspNumber.getEditor()).getTextField();
tf.setDocument(new DoubleDocument());
contentPane1.add(jspNumber);
```

Класс DoubleDocument() был взять отсюда [DoubleDocument](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/extendsPlainDocument.htm)
DoubleDocument() этот класс отлично работает для JTextField, а для JSpinner не срабатывает вовсе.

Comment: @Dimitri, вам удалось решить ту задачу? Если да, расскажите как, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
 jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
 jSpinner1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 0, 14)); 
 jSpinner1.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 1000, 1));
 JFormattedTextField field1 = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor)        
       jSpinner1.getEditor()).getTextField();
 ((NumberFormatter) field1.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);
 DefaultFormatter formatter1 = (DefaultFormatter) field1.getFormatter();
 formatter1.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
 jSpinner1.addChangeListener(e -> jSpinner1StateChanged(e));

 private void jSpinner1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                       
       value = (Integer)jSpinner1.getValue();
       jLabel1.setText(value.toString());
 }
```

[Взято с https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489900/reflecting-the-value-of-jspinner-on-jlabel-when-key-released)